# How to add recurrence event by setting start and end date by using EKRecurrenceRule?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm currently implementing the "add recurrence events to native iOS calendar" by programmatic using EKRecurrenceRule.

In my app has the customized design for week days horizontally displayed with UIButton ((1) - It's a tag value for all weekdays.) like "Monday(2)", "Tuesday(3)", "Wednesday(4)", "Thursday(5)", "Friday(6)", "Saturday(7)", "Sunday(1)"

It's working fine but the problem is, "That event also added to current day" on iOS Calendar. Because I was set the current date to that event start and end date.

But my requirement is When I select "Wednesday" and "Friday", that events repeat weekly like on "Wednesday" and "Friday".

But now that created event is also added on current date like "Today".

How to avoid this one. The created event only repeated each and every "Wednesday" and "Friday"

Kindly check my code,

```
    EKEvent *addEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

    NSDateFormatter *gmtDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [gmtDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];

    NSDate *endDate   = [[NSDate alloc]init];


    NSString *tempDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:00",dateString,self.hourTxtField.text];

    startDate = [gmtDateFormatter dateFromString:tempDateString];

    endDate   = [gmtDateFormatter dateFromString:tempDateString];

    addEvent.startDate = startDate;

    //addEvent.endDate = endDate;

    addEvent.title = self.medicinTxtField.text;

    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:[reminderValue integerValue]];

    [addEvent addAlarm:alarm];


    if ([isRecurrent integerValue] == 1) {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self = %@",@""];

        NSArray *resultdaysInfoArray = [daysInfoArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        //create the recurrence rule here
        EKRecurrenceRule *recurrence;

        if ([resultdaysInfoArray count] > 0) {

            recurrence = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly
                                                                      interval:1
                                                                 daysOfTheWeek:daysOfTheWeekArray
                                                                daysOfTheMonth:nil
                                                               monthsOfTheYear:nil
                                                                weeksOfTheYear:nil
                                                                 daysOfTheYear:nil
                                                                  setPositions:nil
                                                                           end:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            recurrence = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily
                                                                      interval:1
                                                                 daysOfTheWeek:daysOfTheWeekArray
                                                                daysOfTheMonth:nil
                                                               monthsOfTheYear:nil
                                                                weeksOfTheYear:nil
                                                                 daysOfTheYear:nil
                                                                  setPositions:nil
                                                                           end:nil];
        }

        // setting the values directly for testing purpose.
//        EKRecurrenceEnd *endRecurrence = nil;

        EKRecurrenceEnd *endRecurrence;

        NSLog(@"endRecurrence = %@",endRecurrence.endDate);


        if (endRecurrence.endDate != nil ) {

            endRecurrence = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:[endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:[reminderValue integerValue]]];

            recurrence.recurrenceEnd = endRecurrence;
        }
        else
        {
            addEvent.endDate = addEvent.startDate;
        }

        [addEvent addRecurrenceRule: recurrence];
    }

    [addEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    NSError *err;

    [eventStore saveEvent:addEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

    NSLog(@"addEvent.eventIdentifier = %@",addEvent.eventIdentifier);

    self.calendarEventID = addEvent.eventIdentifier;
```

Here in the daysOfTheWeekArray is like below,

[daysOfTheWeekArray addObject:[EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:[sender tag]]];

The above one from UIButton's IBAction function.

I know that issue where it's came from. Because I set it the current date to that event's start and end date.

But may be I missed few lines code "EKRecurrenceRule" for avoid the start and end date values.

So Kindly suggest me for achieve this one.